# Google positioning by concrete words

Tags: positioning, words

I'm having trouble about how to tell google what is my site about. I've a site with a concrete tematic (say A) and directed to a concrete geographic zone (say B).

Then, how can I suggest Google that A + B is a right definition of my site?

Sorry if it is a noob question, but can't find anything concrete and useful about it

Thanks in advance